# Session values getting empty on second page in Iframe

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am having a website where one page includes an Iframe which shows a page from the same website and is in a different folder. There are 7 pages and I have loaded each page by load() of jquery.
I am storing values in session and accessing it on the next page. But when I am trying to get the session values on second page it becomes empty.
I have written session_start() in every page at the beginning. Also tried sending below header

```
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
```

Still getting empty.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    error_reporting(1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vision</title>
    <?php $baseurl ='http://www.localhost/xyz.com/'; ?>

    <link href="<?= $baseurl ?>catalog/view/theme/test/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?= $baseurl ?>custom-lens/custom-lens.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .sec-active{border:2px solid red !important;}
    </style>
    <?php
        if($_REQUEST['prod_id']){   
            $_SESSION['pre_session_data_'.$_REQUEST['prod_id']]['Product_id'] = $_REQUEST['prod_id'];
        }else{  
            die("Invalid Request. Something went wrong. Please reload the url and try again.");
        }
```

Above is the code of upper part of 1st page.

```
$( ".vision-parent" ).click(function(){
        $("#ajax-content").load("./category-ajax.php?vid="+vid+"&prod_id=<?php echo $_REQUEST['prod_id'];?>");
    }
    return false;
});
```

Above is the code of 2nd part at footer on 1st page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <?php
            
            error_reporting(1);
            echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);die;
    
            if($_REQUEST['prod_id'] != $_SESSION['pre_session_data_'.$_REQUEST['prod_id']]['Product_id']){
                die("Invalid Request. Something went wrong. Please reload the url and try again.");
            }
```

Above is the code of 2nd page.

I am not able to find the issue. The session value is displaying on the 1st page but not on 2nd page.

The url from which I am calling is
http://www.localhost/xyz.com/custom-lens/vision.php?prod_id=286

The requested url is
http://www.localhost/xyz.com/custom-lens/category-ajax.php?vid=1&prod_id=286

Comment: What we can not see, in your question, are the actual URLs used by the main page and the iframe. Details matter. If your main page uses "example.com" and your iframe uses "www.example.com" the session might not work because one is on a subdomain.

Comment: Are you running this local, in some sort of sandbox?

Comment: Localhost it is.

Answer (score 1):

session_start must be the first thing to call in your page
[session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.session-start.php)

> ```
> Note:    To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser.
> ```

Comment: Tried that too.